# Wigner-Ekhart theorem for Fermi Golden Rule in semiconductors

Tags: angular-momentum, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, fermis-golden-rule

I have seen many authors mentioning that there is a way to work in total angular momentum basis and calculate the matrix elements using the Wigner-Ekhart theorem.  [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=APsOSXKcJxIC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=semiconductor%20wigner-eckart&source=bl&ots=2OSlys2oGI&sig=lCbKMYNzoFMpUxNU1Sp7lWpVJbM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr17DProbbAhWhpFkKHZl0C2YQ6AEIdjAI#v=onepage&q=wigner-eckart&f=false) the author even says that atomic-like wave functions are a good approximation to an envelope functions (Bloch functions) in certain cases. I suppose, in $\Gamma$ - point... From [here](http://www.spinelektronik.de/tl_files/spinelektronik/documents/Goslar2008/talks/koenig.pdf) it even seems like it should be doable in $kp$ - theory. But after a week of digging into the books I failed to find a single one writing out the integral and explicitly applying Wigner-Ekhart. All just talking and throwing around analogies... Does anybody have a clue on where I could find the actual formalism?

**References:**

1. "Electronic and Optical Properties of Semiconductors: A Study Based on the Empirical Tight Binding Model" by Lok C. Lew Yan Voon (First chapter is enough)
2. Slides by Jurgen Konig, around slide #16-19: http://www.spinelektronik.de/tl_files/spinelektronik/documents/Goslar2008/talks/koenig.pdf

Comment: The question looks interesting and I would like to know more but there are 81 slides in the link you provided. Maybe you’d care to direct the reader to the relevant slides and edit your question so it contains the important details?

Comment: Look at envelope function approach: ~#16-19. It is actually around 50 slides and a lot of them were generated from animations...

Comment: For which element would you like to use WE?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero for the integral over the envelope functions (Bloch states). See, I know that close to $\Gamma$-point Bloch states get atomic-like flavor for GaAs, Ge, Si, and probably more... I'd like to see the explicit expression or at least some theoretical considerations, not semi-philosophical or semi-empirical...

Comment: recommend you edit your post to include additional details.  I dunno where this integral over envelope functions is or what something like this looks like.  It would also make your post more self-contained and more accessible to others.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero My post says "Fermi Golden rule"... If you take any textbook on optical properties of semiconductors and open Fermi Golden rule chapter, you will find the matrix element for absorption/emission of a photon by a semiconductor and see that the envelope part of the matrix element can be factorized out. Usually this integral is extracted from the $kp$-theory, but the total angular momentum basis is not a conventional way to treat it...